# GeoServer WMS layer doesn't see file content

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, sld

I've created a new layer, and styled with an .sld file (categorized by value). It works, if I check with GeoServer OpenLayers Preview, but when I check for this in a .html it doesn't appear. Is the problem with the bounds? I copied it from the URL:

```
...wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=foldrengesekGIS:mercatorvetulet&styles=&bbox=139.0697,36.60050000000007,143.85570000000007,41.53800000000007&width=496&height=512&srs=EPSG:3857&format=application/openlayers
```

Actually there is only one data, but the place is also wrong.

[image: GeoServer OpenLayers preview, showing error]

Comment: The problem is you need to set the projection correctly. You are using lat/lon, but viewing it with spherical mercator, 3857, by the look of it.

Comment: Can you post a link or the code to the HTML file?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html><html>
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>OpenLayers - egyszerű térkép</title>
  <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function init() // az oldal betöltésekor végrehajtandó függvény
   {

Comment: var map = new OpenLayers.Map('terkep_helye', 
       {
         projection: "EPSG:3857", // EPSG:3857 = Spherical Mercator
         maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(139.0697,36.60050000000007,143.85570000000007,41.53800000000007)  
       });
   
     map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM())
     var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "foldrengesekGIS",
        'http..wms',
        {
          layers: ['mercatorvetulet'], 
          isBaseLayer: false,
          transparent: true
        },
        {
singleTile: true
        });     
     
     map.addLayer(wms);